# Moq : how can mock property and side Effect?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, moq

This is test scenario.

when kid age over 3, `IsAdult == true`.

I want test with Moq. But fails because `Age` always return `2` based on setup

How can I test this? Is mocking a bad idea?

using a debug method or brute force was not intended...

```
public class Kid
{
    public virtual float Age { get; private set; } = 0;
    public bool IsAdult { get; private set; }
    private float _ageIncreasePerHour = 1;

    public void OnHourPass()
    {
        Age += _ageIncreasePerHour;

        if (Age >= 3)
        {
            IsAdult = true;
        }
    }

    public void Debug_SetAge(float newAge)
    {
        Age = newAge;
    }
}

public class Test_Kid
{
    //fail. how can i mocking?
    [Test]
    public void WhenAgeOver3_Kid_IsAdult_UseMocking()
    {
        var mockKid = new Mock<Kid> { CallBase = true };
        mockKid.Setup(x => x.Age).Returns(2);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, mockKid.Object.Age);
        mockKid.Object.OnHourPass();
        Assert.AreEqual(3, mockKid.Object.Age); // but 2.
        Assert.AreEqual(true, mockKid.Object.IsAdult); // but false.
    }

    //success. but not intended. Debug-Method is anti pattern!
    [Test]
    public void WhenAgeOver3_Kid_IsAdult_UseDebugMethod()
    {
        var newKid = new Kid();
        newKid.Debug_SetAge(2);
        newKid.OnHourPass();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, newKid.IsAdult);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you mock at all? Couldn´t you just create an instance, call `OnHourPass()` until age is over 3 and then assert `IsAdult`?

Comment: This is just example. in my code, be tested class has many dependencies. I agree your idea, (calling until age to met condition) but some more complex situations it can be difficult...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moq is unable to work with the *private* setter of the `Age` property so this makes things difficult when using Moq as it will throw exception if you try to setup the property's setter to record behaviors (side effects).

You can however avoid using Moq altogether and set the value using [`PrivateObject Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.privateobject.aspx) as a wrapper over the subject under test.

Using `PrivateObject.SetProperty` you can set your initial value for the test and then exercise the test as desired.

Assuming

```
public class Kid {
    public virtual float Age { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAdult { get; private set; }
    private float _ageIncreasePerHour = 1;

    public void OnHourPass() {
        Age += _ageIncreasePerHour;
        if (Age >= 3) {
            IsAdult = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The test would look like this...

```
public void _WhenAgeOver3_Kid_IsAdult() {
    //Arrange
    var initialAge = 2;
    var expectedAge = initialAge + 1;
    var kid = new Kid();
    var wrapper = new PrivateObject(kid);            
    wrapper.SetProperty("Age", initialAge);
    Assert.AreEqual(initialAge, kid.Age);

    //Act
    kid.OnHourPass();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedAge, kid.Age); // should be 3.
    Assert.AreEqual(true, kid.IsAdult); // should be true.
}
```

Another option if you are able to alter the subject would be to refactor the subject to take an optional parameter in its constructor to set the initial `Age`

```
public class Kid {

    public Kid(int initialAge = 0) {
        Age = initialAge;
    }

    public virtual float Age { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAdult { get; private set; }
    private float _ageIncreasePerHour = 1;

    public void OnHourPass() {
        Age += _ageIncreasePerHour;
        if (Age >= 3) {
            IsAdult = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This would then allow the test to be refactored as well to....

```
public void _WhenAgeOver3_Kid_IsAdult() {
    //Arrange
    var initialAge = 2;
    var expectedAge = initialAge + 1;
    var kid = new Kid(initialAge);
    Assert.AreEqual(initialAge, kid.Age);

    //Act
    kid.OnHourPass();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedAge, kid.Age); // should be 3.
    Assert.AreEqual(true, kid.IsAdult); // should be true.
}
```